Huge amount of funds transaction before visa application for PLAB 2
So I'm going to apply for a uk plab 2 visit visa for a span of 1 month in the end of May. My father is going to be my sponsor but last month he paid made a huge transaction of 12337 gbp from his bank account to pay for upgradation of a company car that he was going to get after his promotion. The thing is he was going to pay for this through his provident funds from the company where he currently works at which came a few days later in his bank account. During this span there was very few funds in his account. I am scared that this can lead to the refusal of my visa as it's a huge sum. If someone can help me out in terms of what will be the best way to go about it in terms.of explaining it in my cover letter.
Also a few months ago my sister transferred around 3500 gbp to his bank account as well. Should I make her my co sponsor then or I should just attach a bank statement of the past 3 months only?

Have your father provide you with the supporting paperwork for the provident funds received into his account. UKVI doesn’t expect bank accounts to be static, see Should I submit bank statements when applying for a UK Visa? What do they say about me? Just explain the transaction briefly in your covering letter.
You should aim to provide 6 months’ statements. Explain that your sister credited £3,500 to your father’s account and why. Have your sister provide the paperwork that shows the source of the funds.

Hey thank you so much for replying. Will i need to also attach my sister's bank statements or just an income letter from the place where she works at will be enough. Also what are the more believable reasons as to why she credited such a huge amount because she did it for my visa at first and then we decided to apply for the visa later.

@Anonymous best not to try to second guess the officials. Tell the truth, the whole truth, and nothing but the truth.
